# Django models avoid duplicates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

In models:

```
class Getdata(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE, default="0")
    name = models.ForeignKey(School)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(profile)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id()
```

In templates:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" value="save the data" />
</form>
```

If the user clicks on the save button and the above data is saved in the table, how to avoid the duplicates, i.e. if the user again clicks on the same submit button there should not be another entry for the same values. Or is it something that has to be handled in views?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If an individual field needs to be unique, then you just add `unique=True`:

```
class Getdata(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE, default="0")
    name = models.ForeignKey(School)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(profile)
```

If you want a combination of fields to be unique, you need [unique_together](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class Getdata(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE, default="0")
    name = models.ForeignKey(School)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(profile)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["title", "state", "name"]
```

Comment: Also when getdata is called in views for the second example by default this will return "title", "state" and "name" is it?

Comment: When you reference a Getdata object in a view, you get a Getdata object, with all its fields.

Answer (score 3):

The unique_together also suggested is the best way, but if that's not appropriate for your needs, you can handle it in your form's clean method. eg

```
def clean(self):
   try:
      Getdata.objects.get(title=self.cleaned_data['title'], 
                          state=self.cleaned_data['state'],
                          name=self.cleaned_data['name'],
                          created_by=self.cleaned_data['created_by'] )
      #if we get this far, we have an exact match for this form's data
      raise forms.ValidationError("Exists already!")
   except Getdata.DoesNotExist:
      #because we didn't get a match
      pass

   return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: I've also seen, for the multiple-submit case, people put in JavaScript  that disables the Submit button when it is clicked and the form is submitted.  The best solution is probably a combination of all of these.

Comment: In my code i have done the same thing for the time being..but this was inconsistent from others..so i had to know about this..Next time i can use a proper code instead of hacks..

Answer (score 0):

I think injecting a Jquery/JS code to hide the save button would be a good idea.

Create a custom_validate.js file like below and place it in directory static(static file directory)

```
if (!$) {
    $ = django.jQuery;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[name=_save]").click(function() {
       $("[name=_save]").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
});
```

And in admin.py, add the below code.

```
class CustomDataForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = GetData

class GetDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ....
    .....
    form = CustomDataForm

    class Media:
        js = ('/static/custom_validate.js', )
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself as well, `unique_together` seems to work nicely.

```
class Getdata(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE, default="0")
    name = models.ForeignKey(School)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(profile)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["title", "state", "name"]
```

Comment: are you sure with your `class Meta` if you need brackets after, please add them