# Error trying to access field of a form using form.cleaned_data

Tags: django, forms, models

I need to test some things related to my models and forms, so I open the shell using *python3 manage.py shell*, and I import the model and the form correctly and take a random model and put it in a variable(c1) so I do: 
*form = AvalForm(c1)*

after this:
*form.is_valid()*

When I run this at first time its return the error:

> AttributeError: 'Avaliacao' object has no attribute 'get'

But when I run .is_valid again its ok, return *True*

and I go to the next pass...

I run *form.fields* and its return all fields of the form correctly, until here all seems ok...

But when I try to take an specified field using form.cleaned_data['avaliador'] I have:

> ```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<console>", line 1, in
> > <module> KeyError: 'avaliador'
> ```

But the field appears when I type *form.fields* ...

Well lets to codes:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from jsonfield import JSONField
from site_.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class Criterio(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.label

class Candidato(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default = '')
    github = models.URLField(default = '')
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100, default = '')
    cover_letter = models.TextField(default = '')
    Ensino_superior = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    med = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    #talvez tenha que alterrar essa linha
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='/home/douglas/Documentos/Django/my-second-blog/site_/media', null=True, blank=True)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Avaliacao(models.Model):
    candidato = models.ForeignKey(Candidato)
    criterio = models.ForeignKey(Criterio, default='')
    nota = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
    avaliador = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

    def  __str__(self):
        return str(self.candidato)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Candidato, Criterio, Avaliacao
from django import forms
from .forms import CandForm
from .forms import AvalForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def canditato_list(request):
    candidatos = Candidato.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/candidato_list.html', {'candidatos': candidatos})

def candidato_detalhe(request, pk):
    candidato = get_object_or_404(Candidato, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'app/candidato_detalhe.html', {'candidato': candidato})

def avaliar(request):
    ##################################################################################
    aval = Avaliacao.objects.all()          #
    lista_cand = []                         #
    for a in aval:                          #nesse bloco eu ponho tds os avaliadores
        lc = str(a.avaliador)               #existentes em uma lista    
        lista_cand += [lc]                  #
    ##################################################################################

    if request.method == "POST":
        #############################################
        form2 = AvalForm(request.POST)
        #############################################
        if form2.is_valid():
            #############################################################################################
            avaliador = form2.cleaned_data['avaliador'] ###ai aqui eu guardo o avaliador atual na variavel
            avaliador = str(avaliador)
            #############################################################################################
            ### aqui eu faço o teste
            #############################################################################################
            cont = 0 
            for l in lista_cand:
                if avaliador == l:
                    cont += 1
            #############################################################################################
            post = form2.save(commit=False)
            #avaliador = form2.fields['avaliador']
            post.save()
            #faz redirecionara para uma page que só tenha{'avaliador': avaliador} p/ testar a variavel avaliador
            return redirect('canditato_list') 
    else:
        form2 = AvalForm()
        #avaliador = form2.fields['avaliador']
        #teste
        return render(request, 'app/avaliacao.html', {'criterios': form2,})


def cadastrar(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CandForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('candidato_detalhe', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CandForm()
    return render(request, 'app/cadastro.html', {'form': form})
```

***ps: ignore all comments and all code between ######***

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Candidato, Avaliacao, Teste
from django import forms

class CandForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidato
        fields = ('name', 'e_mail', 'github', 'linkedin', 'Ensino_superior','cover_letter')

class AvalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Avaliacao
        fields = ('candidato','criterio','nota','avaliador')
    #fields = ('v1','v2')
```

**[Edit]**

I am doing a system of registering candidates for a job vacancy, there will be an evaluation system (which is the 'Evaluation' model), the candidate can be evaluated only once per evaluator, what I want to do is a test Before saving the model (.save ()), what is between the first marker ('#####'), shortly after 'def evaluate (request):' is a loop that takes all the evaluators who have made their And saves them in a list. After the second marker we have, after the 'if form2.is_valid ():' I am saving the current evaluator, converted to string, into a variable ('evaluator = form2.cleaned_data [' evaluator '] -' evaluator = str ) '). After that I do the test, which in the case would be another loop that compares this variable that received the evaluator converted to string, with each evaluator that is in the list of evaluators (which I named as 'list_cand', and which is also saving The data converted to strings so that I can do the comparison), the loop will go through this list checking if the string holds in the variable is in some slot in the list, if it is I'm going to make a warning or something, otherwise it continues the Evaluation process. Below the comment '### here I do the test' is a draft of what this test would be.

Comment: why do you have to have "cleaned_data"? I don't see you overwriting it at any point

Comment: I edited my question, take a look..I want to do a test that checks if the evaluator who is evaluating the candidate is not "repeated". It is a system of evaluation of candidates for a job vacancy, and each candidate can only be evaluated once by each evaluator

Comment: Do you have to do it on server side or client side? because if it's server side, you can add "unique_together" to the model and Django will take care of preventing duplicates.

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3053032/3802821 then we can discuss further if it's not an option

Comment: @morinx thanks very much dude!