# What is the best way to dynamically load a specific app in django depending of another class?

Tags: python, django, database

I built a django web app to manage medical datas.
I have many specialities using the same project. I'd like to display specific interfaces/forms/templates...depending of the user speciality.

I'm on django 1.11 python 3.6.

The app is running well. I have patients, and users.
Each user have only one speciality (cardiologist, surgeon...), defined by a specific class and linked to the user by a ForeignKey.

## models.py

```
class Specialite(Auditable): #list of specialites, and link it to user !

id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
spe = models.CharField( max_length = 200, null = False,)
#define which app the specialite is linked to...
data_app = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False, blank = False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.spe 

class Patient(Auditable):

#   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052975/django-models-avoid-duplicates                              
class Meta:
    unique_together = ["nom", "prenom", "dob"]

MALE = "MALE"
FEMALE = "FEMALE"

SEXE = (
    (MALE, 'Homme'),
    (FEMALE, 'Femme'),
)

id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
nom = models.CharField( max_length=50,)
nom_naissance = models.CharField( max_length=50,)
prenom = models.CharField(max_length=150,)
sexe = models.CharField(max_length = 100, 
                        choices = SEXE,
                        )
```

For now, i have one table by patient: first name, last name, dob, weight, height...Only general informations shared by all specialities.

I'd like to create specific onetoone tables depending of the speciality to display relevant informations for each speciality/practicioner.
Each field is based on a [SNOMED CT](http://www.snomed.org/) classification for more consistency and data connection.

I though about many ways:

- A huge model on top with a lot of fields, with abstract = true, and sub models using this model
- A huge model with a lot of fields, and for each speciality specific template, form to update datas, but data might change as long as doctors might have a different analysis of the data...
- Eventually, the one i think would be the more appropriate: an app for each speciality with all the logic of the fields, forms etc... inside the app.

So my choice is more into creating an app for each speciality, linked to the "speciality" model by a foreign key or text (like the name of the app:

```
data_app = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False, blank = False)
```

).

In each app, i have a model with just a class linked to a patient by a OneToOne relationship.

```
class Cardiology (Auditable):

id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
zkf_patient = models.OneToOneField(Patient, on_delete = models.PROTECT, null = True, blank = True)

hta = models.BooleanField()

tobacco = models.BooleanField()
.....
```

For now, i'm ok with creating a new entry for a patient with inline formset factory.
However, what i'd like to do is displaying the appropriate Template/CBV/Urls... depending of the user speciality to edit and display the related information.

For instance, if i'm a cardiologist: show on the main page, along with the "patient" model class details, specific information related to cardiology. But if i'm a surgeon, showing the same page, but with the specific informations for surgery...

I can do that now, i'm using the {% include '...html' %} in my template to insert what i want.

I'm thinking about creating a specific tag to dynamically display the related information...

But i've no clue about how to do for the edit page etc....Except creating a script with bunch of dicts to create the relationships, but it seems to me a nightmare.

What's your opinion, is there a more elegant way, more "logic". Based on names of each class view maybe...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think you're looking for user profiles: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: Hi Rafael, Thanks for your answer. It is not exactly what i'm looking for. I already have additional models extending patient informations. These models are specific of a speciality (also linked to the user by a foreign key). I'd like to automaticaly display to the user the appropriate DetailView,UpdateView... and according templates to display and edit the model...  And i don't really know how to do so...!

Comment: For instance, on my main page, if i have a button "edit past medical history", depending of the speciality, the link should redirect automatically to the appropriate form.

Comment: Have you looked at [generic foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)? Might be a more straightforward way to model your relations. When it comes to customising your views and templates depending on the specialty, that's difficult to answer because we don't know the specifics of what you need. But I'd try to make all your specialty models inherit from an abstract model with some common methods that you override in each specialty to determine the specific forms and logic that is required per specialty.

Comment: Thank you for your nice advice with [generic FK](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations). It looks amazing ! Probably not exactly what i'm looking for, even though your idea of inheriting from an abstract model seems very useful. I'd like to make custom templates and form for each speciality, most of all because i'm looking for a great UX with lot of JS in my templates...It's obviously a lot more work, but UX is greatly enhanced. However, i discovered the django ContentType model, feel there is something to do with that...I'll let you know !

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up with a custom tag...Works well so far :) !

```
#TAGS
from django import template
from django.template.loader import render_to_string #generate a string from a template
import datetime
from django.urls import reverse

from django.template.base import (
    Node, Template, TemplateSyntaxError, TextNode, Variable, token_kwargs,
)

register = template.Library()

def get_activ_specialite(request, context):
    app_name = request.resolver_match.app_name

    if app_name == 'patient':
        #get the specialite of the user
        specialite = request.user.profile.specialite_active.spe
        specialite = '_'.join(specialite.lower().split(' '))
        return specialite


    elif app_name == 'hospitalisation':
        #get the specialite of the service where the patient is hospitalized !
        specialite = context['hospitalisation'].specialite_referente.spe
        specialite = '_'.join(specialite.lower().split(' '))
        return specialite

    return 

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def routing_antecedents(context, destination):
    if 'patient' in context:
        patient = context['patient']
        id = patient.id
    if 'hospitalisation' in context:
        hos = context['hospitalisation']
        id = hos.id
    request = context['request']

    #1/get service référent du patient
    app_name = get_activ_specialite(request, context)

    #2/ redirect to urls...! Name consistency is mandatory !!!
    url = str(app_name + ":" + destination)
    url = reverse(str(url), args=(id,) )
    # return url path ! 
    return url


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def include_antecedents_spe(context, template_name):
    request = context['request']

    #1/get service référent du patient
    app_name = get_activ_specialite(request, context)

    template_name = template_name.replace("'","").replace('"', '')
    template_name = str(str(app_name) + "/" + str(template_name))
    html = render_to_string(template_name, context.flatten())
    return html
```