# How to check if record exists in django mysql before insert into database

Tags: mysql, django

Please pardon me, am still new to djando framework.
This error i always get i run it.

**The view finance_lens_app.views.acct_type didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**
This is my model

```
class Acct_type(models.Model):
    Aid=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    acct_type_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    class Meta:
        db_table="Acct_Type"
```

This is my VIEW.

```
def acct_type(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        request.POST.get('acct_type_name')
        acct_type_record=Acct_type()   
        acct_type_record.save()        
        messages.success(request, 'Account Type Added Successfully...')
        return render(request, "admin_opera/acct_type.html")
```

My Interface HTML

```
<form method="POST"> 
  {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
     <select name="acct_type_name" id="acct_type_name" class="form-control">
              <option value="Assets">Assets</option>
              <option value="Liabilities">Liabilities</option>
              <option value="Equities">Equities</option>
              <option value="Incomes">Incomes</option>
              <option value="Expenses">Expenses</option>
              <option value="Expenses2">Expenses2</option>
              <option value="Expenses3">Expenses3</option>
    </select>
   
   </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Account">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need get the value of `acct_type_name` from the form, and then create the `Acct_type` instance and save.

```py
def acct_type(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        acct_type_name = request.POST.get('acct_type_name')
        acct_type_record=Acct_type(acct_type_name = acct_type_name)   
        acct_type_record.save()        
        messages.success(request, 'Account Type Added Successfully...')
        return render(request, "admin_opera/acct_type.html")
```

If you want to check if a record exists, you need to implement the `clean` function through Django form or add `unique=True` to your model field.

```py
class Acct_type(models.Model):
    Aid=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    acct_type_name=models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table="Acct_Type"
```

Comment: Thank you Gejun, i appreciate your support. it work for inserting (save) record but i want it to check if the record is existing before inserting the record.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3053032/2344011). You can add `unique=True` to your model field.